# Преобразование строки с символом "Т" между датой и временем в timestamp

Tags: java

Надо преобразовать дату в формате `2018-11-07T10:43:41` в timestamp. Я написал функцию конвертации, но она валится из-за символа "Т", который разделяет дату и время. Как написать маску для конвертации даты в таком формате?

```
public static long timestamp(String datetime) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(datetime);
        return parsedDate.getTime();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Illegal pattern component: T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Замени формат в строке:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```